# PostgreSQL not recognize database

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

In a production server (Windows Server 2012 R2), we run out of space in the main HDD where a PostgreSQL 9.3 database was stored, so I had to move out the data directory to another drive. I followed all the steps to do it that, stop the server, move the data directory, change the folder permissions and change the -D start parameters.

I could start the server, but it only shows the default postgres db and user (I checked in pgAdmin and psql). All the files are there, even if I try to recreate the same user, I get an user already exist error. I also confirmed if the server started with the new directory (SHOW data_directory;).

Then I move back all the files to the original drive and I have the same problem.

I also checked the logs, but it shows nothing relevant to the problem.

Comment: Did you copy the *complete* data directory? What log messages were written during startup? Can you copy and paste the exact result for `\l` in `psql`?

Comment: Looks like some file went corrupted in the transfer. I copied everything again y works perfectly.